# Rails migration gives me an error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to create a create_posts migration.

However I get this error.

```
== 20140528222521 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:posts)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table posts has no column named description: CREATE  INDEX "index_posts_on_description" ON "posts" ("description")/Users/Hyunsoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Add the migration so people can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you *forgot* to add `description` field in the migration for `CreatePosts` BUT you are adding an index on that non-existing field which is causing the error.

What you need to do is add `description` field in the migration as below:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      ### ...
      t.string :description  ## <== Add this
      ### ...
    end
  end
end
```